# Remove all keys that have values of N/A, -, or empty strings

Tags: python, json, django

```
import json

def clean_data():
  r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
  return r.json()

print(clean_data())
```

Example Input

```
{"name":{"first":"Daniel","middle":"N/A","last":"Smith"},"age":45}
```

Example Output

```
{"name":{"first":"Daniel","last":"Smith"},"age":45}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the response. Cleaning won't happen by itself.

Comment: Also, there is no benefit to ask on SO for solution of a challenge

Comment: Also, you've imported `json` but you're not using it, while `requests` is in the code but not imported.

Answer (score 2):

You can recursively solve this

```py
import json
import requests


r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
data = r.json()

def clean_data(data):
    if(isinstance(data, dict)):
        to_be_deleted = []
        for k in data:
            if(isinstance(data[k], dict)):
                new_val = clean_data(data[k])
                data[k] = new_val
                
            if(isinstance(data[k], list)):
                new_val = clean_data(data[k])
                data[k] = new_val
                
            elif(isinstance(data[k], str)):
                if(data[k] == 'N/A'):
                    to_be_deleted.append(k)
                    
        for i in to_be_deleted:
            del data[i]
        return data
            
    if(isinstance(data, list)):
        to_be_deleted = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if(isinstance(data[i], dict)):
                new_val = clean_data(data[i])
                data[i] = new_val
                
            if(isinstance(data[i], list)):
                new_val = clean_data(data[k])
                data[i] = new_val
                
            elif(isinstance(data[i], str)):
                if(data[i] == 'N/A'):
                    to_be_deleted.append(i)
        for i in to_be_deleted:
            del data[i]
        return data
    
clean_data(data)
```

```
data = data = {"name":{"first":"Daniel","middle":"N/A","last":"Smith", "haha": {'hihi':1, "hoho":"N/A"}},"age":45, "hehe":[1,2,3,4,"N/A"]}
clean_data(data)
# {'name': {'first': 'Daniel', 'last': 'Smith', 'haha': {'hihi': 1}}, 'age': 45, 'hehe': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import requests


r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
data = r.json()


def clean_data(data):
  if (isinstance(data, dict)):
    to_be_deleted = []
    for j in data:
      if (isinstance(data[j], dict)):
        new_val = clean_data(data[j])
        data[j] = new_val

      if (isinstance(data[j], list)):
        new_val = clean_data(data[j])
        data[j] = new_val

      elif (isinstance(data[j], str)):
        if (data[j] == 'N/A' or data[j] == '-' or data[j] == ''):
          to_be_deleted.append(j)

    for i in to_be_deleted:
      del data[i]
    return data

  if (isinstance(data, list)):
    to_be_deleted = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
      if (isinstance(data[i], dict)):
        new_val = clean_data(data[i])
        data[i] = new_val

      if (isinstance(data[i], list)):
        new_val = clean_data(data[i])
        data[i] = new_val

      elif (isinstance(data[i], str)):
        if (data[i] == 'N/A' or data[i] == '-' or data[i] == ''):
          to_be_deleted.append(i)
    for i in to_be_deleted:
      del data[i]
    return data

print("Original Data : ",data)
print("Cleaned Data : ",clean_data(data))
```

Output :

Original Data :  {'name': {'first': 'Robert', 'middle': '', 'last': 'Smith'}, 'age': 25, 'DOB': '-', 'hobbies': ['running', 'coding', '-'], 'education': {'highschool': 'N/A', 'college': 'Yale'}}

Cleaned Data :  {'name': {'first': 'Robert', 'last': 'Smith'}, 'age': 25, 'hobbies': ['running', 'coding'], 'education': {'college': 'Yale'}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import requests
import json

def clean(data):
  for i in list(data):
    v = data[i]
    if type(v) == dict:
      clean(v)
    if type(v) == list:
      if '' in v:
        v.remove('')
      elif '-' in v:
        v.remove('-')
      elif 'N/A' in v:
        v.remove('N/A')
    if type(v) == str:
      if v in ['N/A', '', '-']:
        data.pop(i)

def clean_data():
  r = requests.get('https://coderbyte.com/api/challenges/json/json-cleaning')
  print(json.dumps(r.json()))
  d = json.loads(r.text)
  clean(d)
  return json.dumps(d)
```