# how to remove key basis on valuein javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have e object which have value "ABC" i want to remove key basis on value. kindly check below code

```
let data= {"name":{"first":"Add","middle":"N/A","last":"khan","Country":"N/A"},"age":12};
```

Remove all keys that have values of N/A, -, or empty strings. If one of these values appear in an array, remove that single item from the array. Then console log the modified object as a string.

Comment: I just added the other two exclusion cases that I didn't noticed from your answer. But you could clarify your answer a bit. Do you want it to be recursively? Do you really want to modify the original object or should it result in a completely new object?

Answer (score 0):

To remove keys based on value, you can first filter the keys, and then rebuild the object. For this specific case, I would do it like:

```js
const filteredKeys = Object.keys(data.name)
  .filter(key => data.name[key] != "N/A" && data.name[key] != "-" && data.name[key] != "")
const name = { ...filteredKeys.reduce((prev, key) => ({...prev, [key]: data.name[key] }), {}) }
const result = { ...data, name }
```

For the last part, if you want to just console log as a string, you can serialize it:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.name))
```

But if you want to join the name parts, you have to again use the object keys:

```js
const name = Object.keys(result.name).map(part => result.name[part]).join(" ")
console.log(name)
```

Comment: pbotas i want answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062074/remove-all-keys-that-have-values-of-n-a-or-empty-strings

Comment: Then what you want is in `result` variable